# Can't figure out this complex query (counting num of applications people submitted each time before landing a job for each job they've ever landed)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two tables, the first one **ApplicationTable** has a record of every job application a person submitted, the date of that submission, and whether they landed the job. For example, you can see that Dan had to submit three applications before he landed his first job 'c'.

**ApplicationTable**

| ApplicationID | JobId | Name | ApplicationDate | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | Dan | 2020-01-01 | rejected |
| 2 | b | Dan | 2020-01-01 | rejected |
| 3 | c | Dan | 2020-01-01 | accepted |
| 4 | d | Dan | 2021-02-01 | accepted |
| 5 | e | Dan | 2022-02-01 | rejected |
| 6 | f | Dan | 2022-02-01 | accepted |
| 7 | a | Leo | 2020-01-02 | rejected |
| 8 | b | Leo | 2020-01-02 | rejected |
| 9 | e | Leo | 2022-02-03 | rejected |
| 10 | g | Leo | 2022-02-05 | accepted |

The second table, **JobTable**, has a record of every Job that was landed, which person landed it, and when the job ended (if the date is null, it is an ongoing job)

**JobTable**

| Name | JobId | JobStartDate | JobEndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dan | c | 2020-03-01 | 2021-01-01 |
| Dan | d | 2021-03-01 | 2022-01-01 |
| Dan | f | 2022-04-01 | Null |
| Leo | g | 2022-05-01 | Null |

I am trying to write a query that will calculate the number of applications it took a person to land a job. The final output should look like the table below with NumApplications being the number of applications a person had to submit before they landed a job. As you can see it took 3 application submissions before Dan landed his first job 'c' and then when job 'c' ended it only took one application for him to land the next job 'd'.

| Name | JobId | NumApplications |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Dan | c | 3 |
| Dan | d | 1 |
| Dan | f | 2 |
| Leo | g | 4 |

I've tried to brainstorm solutions but I haven't made any notable progress. I know I should use the JobStartDate and JobEndDate as checkpoints for when to start and stop counting applications, and also that it's important to distinguish if it's a person's first job or if they came from a previous job they just finished, but other than that I am lost. Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider this.

```sql
SELECT Name, JobId, COUNT(*) OVER w1 AS NumApplications FROM (
  SELECT *, COUNT(1) OVER w0 - COUNTIF(Status <> 'accepted') OVER w0 AS part
    FROM ApplicationTable
  WINDOW w0 AS (
    PARTITION BY Name
        ORDER BY UNIX_DATE(ApplicationDate)
        RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
  )
) QUALIFY ANY_VALUE(Status) OVER (w1 ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND CURRENT ROW) = 'accepted'
WINDOW w1 AS (PARTITION BY Name, part);
```

[image]